# How to fix Python PIP update failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, meraki-api

I am trying to install and use python on Windows 11 for purposes of Meraki API calls. I have installed Python version 3.11 and am now trying to run

pip install --upgrade requests

pip install --upgrade meraki

but these command return the following error

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/requests/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

I don't think the firewall is blocking it but I am not sure what I need to look for in the firewall - does anyone know the addresses that need to be unblocked?

Or is there another reason for this error?

Thanks!

I tried adding a firewall rule but didn't know what I needed to add.

Comment: did you try using VPN? if not, give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another pip index-url

For example:

`pip install --upgrade requests -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn`

Comment: thanks for the reply! When I tied that I got;

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/requests/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

However if I navigate to that url in a  browser it resolves no problem :(